# How to use Grid in Tailwind?

Tags: typescript, react-native, tailwind-css

I wanted to try out grids in our React Native app to see how it would look, however I don't seem to be able to get it working. I´ve tried to read up on it, but I'm pretty new so I'm not certain if the problems is from my lacking knowledge in React Native, Typescript or Tailwind... I get the "`grid`unknown or invalid utility". I simply want to see how the text would look beside each other.

```
    <>
      <View style={tw`grid grid-cols-3 bg-pink-200`}>
        <Text>1</Text>
        <Text>2</Text>
        <Text>3</Text>
        </View>
    </>
```

Comment: Tailwind works with classes, so you probably need to use `className=“grid grid-cols-3 bg-pink-200”` instead of style.

Comment: Which package is you are using? Check whether your package support `grid` utility of tailwindcss.

Answer (score 0):

React Native uses similar style properties as CSS, but it's not CSS. React Native [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex) doesn't have a grid concept.

I guess you are using [tailwind-react-native-classnames](https://github.com/jaredh159/tailwind-react-native-classnames). You can check [supported utilities](https://github.com/jaredh159/tailwind-react-native-classnames/blob/master/supported-utilities.md) for it.